# Setting multiple and large print areas

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set large and multiple print areas in excel. I have several documents that is created in excel, and for each range area I am trying to set the print area.

This is my code:

```
Sub SetPrintArea()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim yRng1() As Variant
    Dim yRng2() As Variant
    Dim yRng3() As Variant
    Dim yRng4() As Variant
    Dim yRng5() As Variant
    Dim yRng6() As Variant
    Dim yRng7() As Variant
    Dim yRng8() As Variant
    Dim yRng9() As Variant
    Dim yRng10() As Variant
    Dim yRng11() As Variant
    Dim yRng12() As Variant
    Dim yRng13() As Variant
    Dim yRng14() As Variant
    Dim yRng15() As Variant
    Dim yRng16() As Variant
    Dim yRng17() As Variant
    Dim yRng18() As Variant
    Dim yRng19() As Variant
    Dim yRng20() As Variant
    Dim combinedArrays() As Variant
    Dim printRange As Range
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Manifest")

    yRng1 = Array(ws.Range("A1:W59"), ws.Range("A62:W120"), ws.Range("A123:W181"), ws.Range("A184:W242"))
    yRng2 = Array(ws.Range("A245:W303"), ws.Range("A306:W364"), ws.Range("A367:W425"), ws.Range("A428:W486"), ws.Range("A489:W547"))
    yRng3 = Array(ws.Range("A550:W608"), ws.Range("A611:W669"), ws.Range("A672:W730"), ws.Range("A733:W791"), ws.Range("A794:W852"))
    yRng4 = Array(ws.Range("A855:W913"), ws.Range("A916:W974"), ws.Range("A977:W1035"), ws.Range("A1038:W1096"))
    yRng5 = Array(ws.Range("A1099:W1157"), ws.Range("A1160:W1218"), ws.Range("A1221:W1279"), ws.Range("A1282:W1340"), ws.Range("A1343:W1401"))
    yRng6 = Array(ws.Range("A1404:W1462"), ws.Range("A1465:W1523"), ws.Range("A1526:W1584"), ws.Range("A1587:W1645"), ws.Range("A1648:W1706"))
    yRng7 = Array(ws.Range("A1709:W1767"), ws.Range("A1770:W1828"), ws.Range("A1831:W1889"), ws.Range("A1892:W1950"), ws.Range("A1953:W2011"))
    yRng8 = Array(ws.Range("A2014:W2072"), ws.Range("A2075:W2133"), ws.Range("A2136:W2194"), ws.Range("A2197:W2255"), ws.Range("A2258:W2316"))
    yRng9 = Array(ws.Range("A2319:W2377"), ws.Range("A2380:W2438"), ws.Range("A2441:W2499"), ws.Range("A2502:W2560"), ws.Range("A2563:W2621"))
    yRng10 = Array(ws.Range("A2624:W2682"), ws.Range("A2685:W2743"), ws.Range("A2746:W2804"), ws.Range("A2807:W2865"), ws.Range("A2868:W2926"))
    yRng11 = Array(ws.Range("A2929:W2987"), ws.Range("A2990:W3048"), ws.Range("A3051:W3109"), ws.Range("A3112:W3170"), ws.Range("A3173:W3231"))
    yRng12 = Array(ws.Range("A3234:W3292"), ws.Range("A3295:W3353"), ws.Range("A3356:W3414"), ws.Range("A3417:W3475"), ws.Range("A3478:W3536"))
    yRng13 = Array(ws.Range("A3539:W3597"), ws.Range("A3600:W3658"), ws.Range("A3661:W3719"), ws.Range("A3722:W3780"), ws.Range("A3783:W3841"))
    yRng14 = Array(ws.Range("A3844:W3902"), ws.Range("A3905:W3963"), ws.Range("A3966:W4024"), ws.Range("A4027:W4085"), ws.Range("A4088:W4146"))
    yRng15 = Array(ws.Range("A4149:W4207"), ws.Range("A4210:W4268"), ws.Range("A4271:W4329"), ws.Range("A4332:W4390"), ws.Range("A4393:W4451"))
    yRng16 = Array(ws.Range("A4454:W4512"), ws.Range("A4515:W4573"), ws.Range("A4576:W4634"), ws.Range("A4637:W4695"), ws.Range("A4698:W4756"))
    yRng17 = Array(ws.Range("A4759:W4817"), ws.Range("A4820:W4878"), ws.Range("A4881:W4939"), ws.Range("A4942:W5000"), ws.Range("A5003:W5061"))
    yRng18 = Array(ws.Range("A5064:W5122"), ws.Range("A5125:W5183"), ws.Range("A5186:W5244"), ws.Range("A5247:W5305"), ws.Range("A5308:W5366"))
    yRng19 = Array(ws.Range("A5369:W5427"), ws.Range("A5430:W5488"), ws.Range("A5491:W5549"), ws.Range("A5552:W5610"), ws.Range("A5613:W5671"))
    yRng20 = Array(ws.Range("A5674:W5732"), ws.Range("A5735:W5793"), ws.Range("A5796:W5854"), ws.Range("A5857:W5915"), ws.Range("A5918:W5976"))
    
    combinedArrays = Array(yRng1, yRng2, yRng3, yRng4, yRng5, yRng6, yRng7, yRng8, yRng9, yRng10, yRng11, yRng12, yRng13, yRng14, yRng15, yRng16, yRng17, yRng18, yRng19, yRng20)


    Set printRange = combinedArrays(0)(0)

    For i = 0 To UBound(combinedArrays)
        For j = 0 To UBound(combinedArrays(i))
            If i = 0 And j = 0 Then
                Set printRange = combinedArrays(i)(j)
            Else
                Set printRange = Union(printRange, combinedArrays(i)(j))
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    ws.PageSetup.printArea = printRange.Address

End Sub
```

However, when I try to print, I only get 18 pages, which is up to and including the range "A1038:W1096". I want to have one page for each range I have defined above.

Is this a limitation in excel? Or am I doing something wrong?

brds,

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, I just used the office JavaScript:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
let manifestSheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Manifest");
// Set print area for selectedSheet to range "A1:D5, A7:D12, A14:D19"
let yRng1 = "A1:W59, A62:W120, A123:W181, A184:W242"
let yRng2 = "A245:W303, A306:W364, A367:W425, A428:W486, A489:W547"
let yRng3 = "A550:W608, A611:W669, A672:W730, A733:W791, A794:W852"
let yRng4 = "A855:W913, A916:W974, A977:W1035, A1038:W1096"
let yRng5 = "A1099:W1157, A1160:W1218, A1221:W1279, A1282:W1340, A1343:W1401"
let yRng6 = "A1404:W1462, A1465:W1523, A1526:W1584, A1587:W1645, A1648:W1706"
let yRng7 = "A1709:W1767, A1770:W1828, A1831:W1889, A1892:W1950, A1953:W2011"
let yRng8 = "A2014:W2072, A2075:W2133, A2136:W2194, A2197:W2255, A2258:W2316"
let yRng9 = "A2319:W2377, A2380:W2438, A2441:W2499, A2502:W2560, A2563:W2621"
let yRng10 = "A2624:W2682, A2685:W2743, A2746:W2804, A2807:W2865, A2868:W2926"
let yRng11 = "A2929:W2987, A2990:W3048, A3051:W3109, A3112:W3170, A3173:W3231"
let yRng12 = "A3234:W3292, A3295:W3353, A3356:W3414, A3417:W3475, A3478:W3536"
let yRng13 = "A3539:W3597, A3600:W3658, A3661:W3719, A3722:W3780, A3783:W3841"
let yRng14 = "A3844:W3902, A3905:W3963, A3966:W4024, A4027:W4085, A4088:W4146"
let yRng15 = "A4149:W4207, A4210:W4268, A4271:W4329, A4332:W4390, A4393:W4451"
let yRng16 = "A4454:W4512, A4515:W4573, A4576:W4634, A4637:W4695, A4698:W4756"
let yRng17 = "A4759:W4817, A4820:W4878, A4881:W4939, A4942:W5000, A5003:W5061"
let yRng18 = "A5064:W5122, A5125:W5183, A5186:W5244, A5247:W5305, A5308:W5366"
let yRng19 = "A5369:W5427, A5430:W5488, A5491:W5549, A5552:W5610, A5613:W5671"
let yRng20 = "A5674:W5732, A5735:W5793, A5796:W5854, A5857:W5915, A5918:W5976"

let printRanges = [yRng1, yRng2, yRng3, yRng4, yRng5, yRng6, yRng7, yRng8, yRng9, yRng10, yRng11, yRng12, yRng13, yRng14, yRng15, yRng16, yRng17, yRng18, yRng19, yRng20];
let printRange = printRanges.join(',');

manifestSheet.getPageLayout().setPrintArea(printRange);
```

}

Which solved my problem.